# Error message when running .ics script?

Tags: php, mysql, icalendar

When I run the following code and open in ical I get this message *"Calendar can’t read this calendar file. No events have been added to your calendar."* Any idea where I have gone wrong?

```
require_once('calendar.php');
$start = date('Ymd', $row['CourseStartDate']) . 'T' .date('His', $row['CourseStartDate']) . 'z';
$end = date('Ymd', $row['CourseEndDate']) . 'T' .date('His', $row['CourseEndDate']) . 'z';
header("content-type:text/calendar;charset=utf-8");
header("content-disposition:inline;filename=bookings.ics");
    echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
    echo "VERSION:2.0\n";
    echo "METHOD:REQUEST\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
    echo "UID:".date('Ymd') . 'T' .date('His').rand()."firstaid4life.com";
    echo "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."/n";
    echo "DTSTART:{$start}\n";
    echo "DTEND:{$end}\n";
    echo "SUMMARY:{$row['CourseTitle']}\n";
    echo "ATTENDEES:{$row['Attendees']}\n";
    echo "END:VEVENT\n";
}
    echo "END: VCALENDAR\n";
```

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently the resulting file is malformed. Could you provide the output of the above script? As we don't know the content of your database nor the queries, it's hard to find the error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ics specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1), the lines should be seperated by a CRLF squence, so you should use `\r\n` for linebreaks.

Also note that the line

```
echo "UID:".date('Ymd') . 'T' .date('His').rand()."firstaid4life.com";
echo "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."/n";
```

are completely missing a linebreak. `/n` is *not* a newline, `\n` would be correct. Your code should be at least (probably replacing all `\n`s with `\r\n`s)

```
echo "UID:".date('Ymd') . 'T' .date('His').rand()."firstaid4life.com\n";
echo "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\n";
```